# *ngFor not registering in Angular MatDialog

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an Angular project where some linked notes are being passed through to a mat dialog in the form of an array, however using an `*ngFor` loop to display all the usernames from the linked notes does not display anything on screen, as seen in the code snippet below:

```html
<div *ngFor="let linkedNote of linkedNotes; let i = index">
   <h6 >{{linkedNote['userName']}}</h6>
</div>
```

Furthermore, I have tried referencing a single username from the linkedNotes array and this has worked, meaning I am referencing the array correctly:

```html
<h6 >{{linkedNotes[2]['userName']}}</h6>
```

Can `*ngFor` loops work within a mat dialog and if so what needs to change in order for it to work?

Comment: How does the data look inside the `linkedNotes` object? And how is it initialized?

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with it, we propably need more code than the snippet your provide. `*ngFor` should work pretty much everywhere

Comment: @Chund me neither, other than there must be something wrong in the initialization of `linkedNotes` or adding data into it.

Comment: I suspect the items are being `push`ed into the array. When change detection runs, it won't catch the change because the reference is the same. Can you post some code from the `.ts` file where `linkedNotes` is populated?

Comment: ```
```ngOnInit(){
    for (let x = 0; x < this.data.linkedPNs.length; x++){
    this.linkedNotes.push(this.data.linkedPNs[x])
    }
    console.log(this.linkedNotes)
  }
```

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I think you right. Is there a way to run another change detection after the array is populated?

Comment: Appreciate all this support. I'm still learning the ropes here.

Answer (score 0):

You can either inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into the component and detect changes manually:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  for (let x = 0; x < this.data.linkedPNs.length; x++) {
    this.linkedNotes.push(this.data.linkedPNs[x]);
  }
  this.cd.detectChanges();
  console.log(this.linkedNotes);
}
```

Or, you can also replace the array altogether instead of pushing into it. I find this method to be cleaner (and does not require manual change detection):

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.linkedNotes = [...this.data.linkedPNs];
}
```

Comment: Have tried both these solutions with no success, as well as assigning the value of linkedNotes on creation:
`
 export class Photoview  implements OnInit {

    linkedNotes: any[] = [...this.data.linkedPNs];
`
The console log of linkedNotes value displays an array of 11 objects.

Comment: And when I try to inspect the divs that should be generated in the console, all that exists where the divs should be is a commented out line:

`<!---->`

Comment: Try assigning the values _when you have them_, not at the moment when you declare the `linkedNotes` property. The assignment should happen as depicted in the answer, inside the curly braces of `ngOnInit`, or in the constructor if data is injected using `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` injection token.

Comment: I've tried both of these, must be something I'm missing out or failed to mention to you.. I have found a work around by populating the div using DOM in the typescript side:
`var replies = "Responses:"
  for (let x = 0; x < this.linkedNotes.length; x++){
replies = replies + "<h6 style='padding: 10px; background-color:#8c8d8d; color:white; border-radius:25px'>  " + this.linkedNotes[x]['userName'] + "</h6>"
    }

    document.getElementById("responses").innerHTML = replies
  }`
Really appreciate all the support